# Изменить порядок бит в массиве byte[]

Tags: c#, массивы, byte

Доброго времени суток.

Возникла проблема, которую пока не получается явно решить. Есть массив значений byte, в котором записаны шестнадцатеричные значения в виде последовательности:

```
0xBB, 0x44, 0x11, 0x22
```

Необходимо получить соответственно значения

```
0xDD, 0x22, 0x88, 0x44
```

Т.е. поменять местами биты в каждом байте и записать их снова в виде шестнадцатеричных значений. Проблема в том, что я знаю как это сделать в двоичной системе, но не имею понятия, как их перевернуть в шестнадцатиричной, там же и оставив. Для двоичной использую конструкцию:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    program_data_tosend[i + offset] = (byte)(program_data_tosend[i + offset] << 1);
    if (((program_data_receive[i + offset] >> i) & 1) > 0)
    {
        program_data_tosend[i + offset] = (byte)(program_data_tosend[i + offset] | 1);
    }
}
```

Буду рад любой помощи и любым подсказкам.

Comment: А что значит "они там в шестнадцетиричной" - это у вас текстовая строка в которой прямо вот так текстом и записано "0xBB ..." ?

Comment: просто Byte в памяти компа всегда в двоичной, а то что их значально вводили или выводят в шестнадцетиричной - это только вопрос ввода-вывода

Comment: файл, из которого я беру значения, содержит набор бит, т.е. последовательности из 0 и 1. Мне нужно их сосчитать, вывести в виде шестнадцатеричного массива, после чего перевернуть биты в каждом байте и снова вывести. Застопорился на второй части проблемы

Comment: если они все  таки в текстовом виде, то вам надо просто поменять местами четные-нечентные символы и заменить цифры-буквы на их развернутый вариант просто по табличке типа F и 0 не меняются, 1 становится 8, 2 - 4, и т.п.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Довольно простой и быстрый, но слегка трудный для понимания метод с [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseByteWith64BitsDiv):

```
b = (byte)((b * 0x0202020202 & 0x010884422010) % 1023);
```

где `b` - собственно байт, биты в котором нужно развернуть.

Соответственно, в вашем случае можно просто выполнить данную конструкцию в цикле:

```
var input = new byte[] { 0xBB, 0x44, 0x11, 0x22 };

for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    input[i] = (byte)((input[i] * 0x0202020202 & 0x010884422010) % 1023);
}
```

В результате, содержимым `input` становится

> 0xdd, 0x22, 0x88, 0x44

Либо с использованием LINQ:

```
var result = input.Select(b => (byte)((b * 0x0202020202 & 0x010884422010) % 1023));
```

Answer (score 0):

Для разворота порядка бит в байте вы можете использовать следующий код

```
byte b = 0xAB;
byte temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    temp = (temp << 1) | (b & 0x1);
    b >>= 1;
}
b = temp;
```